# spring security user agreement page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to implement a EULA page that the users must agree with in my spring-security enabled application, and I'm wondering what's the best way to go about this.
The current implementation that I have is using a authentication-success-handler-ref to redirect a successfully authenticated user to the EULA page if it hasnt been accepted already. This works fine, but the problem is that I cannot force the user to accept the EULA since the user is already authenticated, he/she can simply change the URL and go on their merry way.

I was thinking that maybe a filter would be appropriate? A filter that would sit last in the filter chain and redirect the user to the EULA page if it's not accepted yet or just let it go through if it is. Should then the EULA page have permitAll in intercept-url ?

Or maybe a completely different approach (custom expression evaluator?).

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: One way to do is to assign a valid user role (GrantedAuthority) when a user has accepted the EULA. Access to other parts of the application should be allowed when user has that role.

Answer (score 0):

I like the filter idea.

The specific access level depends on whether anonymous users have to accept the EULA. If so, then `permitAll` makes sense. If you require authentication and long-term tracking of the EULA, then add an `eulaAgreed` property to the account, and use `isAuthenticated` on the EULA page.